# send data from component to child component in vue 3

Tags: javascript, laravel, api, vue.js, vuejs3

i´m trying to send data from my parent component `formTelemarketing` to my child component `nAsignedCalls` to do this, i´m doing a prop in parent  `props: { register: Number },` and when i clicked my button submit (not it´s a submit button) should fill a table, my action button call a function `searchRegisters` and get values from form and use $emit to send prop to my component

```
this.$emit("registers", getCall(toRef(param_search,'param_search')))
```

and in my child component included in parent i have:

```
<div id="app5">
     <nAsignedCalls @registers="getCall"></nAsignedCalls> 
</div>
```

and in my child component in export default i have props:['register'], and in my table into this component i have a for-each that should get all data from this prop... I don´t have any error in console but i can´t show my data

```
{{ (register) ? register : "vacio" }}
            <template v-for="item of register"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.name) ? item.name : '' }} </td>
```

for example it´s my structure i have a condition to know if register it´s filled, always return "vacio".

this it´s my props definition in my child component:

```
export default defineComponent({
        name: 'nAsignedCalls',
        props:['register'],
```

My API it´s ok, in console network tab i can show response ok `{"data":[{"id":895,"name":"Aguilera Muriel Fatimas",` i have more data...

I don´t know that i´m doing wrong i´m something newbie in vue...

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

**update**

first of all, i´m using composition API in my proyect.

Now, in my child component i define my event

```
// personaliced event
            const emitMyEvent = (event) => emit('registers', event);

            return { 
                remove,
                searchId,
                searchName,
                searchPhone,
                edit,
                getResults,
                getPage,
                emitMyEvent,
                getCall
            }
```

In my app.js i redefine app5:

```
const app5 = createApp({
    components:{
        nAsignedCalls
    },
    setup() {
        const getCall = (event) => console.log('getCall(): ' + event.target.id);
        return { getCall }
    }
})
app5.mount('#app5')
```

but when i clicked my button, i can´t show anything in my web or in my console

**my button:**

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="Buscar registros" @click="searchRegisters()">
```

all content script in my parent component where i´m doing click in my button and this call to function.

Update my question with all code from my parent component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container mt-3 bg-white shadow rounded p-3">
        <div class="row justify-content-start mt-4">
            <div class="col-md-6 ml-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <select class="form-control" name="teleoperator" id="teleoperator_select" placeholder="Teleoperadora">
                            <option hidden>Teleoperadora</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-start align-items-center mt-4">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" required>
                    <label for="address">Dirección</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required>
                    <label for="city">Ciudad</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-item">
                    <input type="text" name="cp" id="postal_code" required>
                    <label for="postal_code">Código Postal</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-dark" value="Buscar registros" @click="searchRegisters">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container mt-3 bg-white shadow rounded p-3 ">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#nasigned">No asignadas</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#asigned">Asignadas</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="container" style="width: 95% !important;">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade-in" id="asigned">
                        <div id="app4">
                            <asignedCalls></asignedCalls> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade-in active" id="nasigned">
                        <div id="app5">
                            <nAsignedCalls @registers="getCall"></nAsignedCalls> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    import { onMounted, defineComponent, toRef } from 'vue';
    import useNregister from '../composables/ncalls'
    import asignedCalls from './roomBooss/asignedCalls';
    import nAsignedCalls from './roomBooss/nasignedCalls';

    export default defineComponent({
        components: {asignedCalls, nAsignedCalls},
        data(){
            return{
                items: [],
                    pagination: {
                        current_page: 1,
                    },
                register: 0,
            }
        },
        props: { register: Number },
        
        setup(props, { emit }, context) {
            const emitMyEvent = (event) => emit('registers', event);

            var param_search = {};
            const { getCall, deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = useNregister()
            

            function remove(id) {
                deleteCalls(id)
            }
            
            function searchId(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('id_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchName(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('name_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchPhone(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('phone_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function edit(action) {
                window.location.href = '/roomboss/telemarketing/call/'+action+"/edit";
            }

            function show(action) {
                window.location.href = '/roomboss/telemarketing/call/'+action;
            }

            function getPage(page){
                getItems(page);
            }

            function searchRegisters(){
                var address = "";
                var city = "";
                var cp = "";

                address = document.getElementById("address").value
                if( address != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "address";
                    param_search["value"] = address;
                }

                city = document.getElementById("city").value
                if( city != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "city";
                    param_search["value"] = city;
                }

                cp = document.getElementById("postal_code").value
                if( cp != "" ) {
                    param_search["parameter"] = "cp";
                    param_search["value"] = cp
                }

                context.emit("registers", getCall(toRef(param_search,'param_search')))

            }

            return { 
                remove,
                searchId,
                searchName,
                searchPhone,
                edit,
                show,
                getResults,
                getPage,
                getCall,
                searchRegisters,
                emitMyEvent
            }
        }
    })

</script>
```

**update**

my data it´s send i can show it in network tab, but my table it´s empty and

```
<tbody>
            <template v-for="item of registers"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.name) ? item.name : '' }} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.address) ? item.address : ''}}</td>
                    <td>{{ (item.province) ? item.province : ''}} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.city) ? item.city : ''}} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.cp) ? item.cp : ''}} </td>
                    <td>{{ (item.phone) ? item.phone : ''}} </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="text-light" :class="item.status.class_span">
                            {{ (item) ? item.status.name : 'null' }}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="hover-text">
                            <div class="icon-actions">
                                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-1">   
                                        <i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-actions">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <button class="tooltip-text btn" id="edit" @click="edit(item.id)"><i class="fas fa-2x fa-edit"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
```

my script in component `nAsignedCalls`, i tryed with `registers` in for and `emitMyEvent` and `newRegisters`

```
<script>
    import useNregister from '../../composables/ncalls'
    import { onMounted, defineComponent } from 'vue'
    
    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'nAsignedCalls',
        emits: ['registers'],
        data(){
            return{
                items: [],
                    pagination: {
                        current_page: 1,
                    },
                newRegisters: Object.assign({}, this.registers),
            }
        },

        
        setup(props, { emit }) {
            const { getCall, deleteCalls, queryForKeywords, getResults, getItems } = useNregister()          

            function remove(id) {
                deleteDates(id)
            }
            
            function searchId(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('id_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchName(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('name_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function searchPhone(action) {
                let id = document.getElementsByClassName('phone_search')[0].value
                const params = [action, id];
                
                queryForKeywords(params)
            }

            function edit(action) {
                window.location.href = '/roomboss/calls/'+action+"/edit";
            }


            function getPage(page){
                getItems(page);
            }

            // personaliced event
            const emitMyEvent = (event) => emit('registers', event);

            return { 
                remove,
                searchId,
                searchName,
                searchPhone,
                edit,
                getResults,
                getPage,
                emitMyEvent,
                getCall
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where are the props for the child?  In Vue its "props down, events up"

Comment: @Dexygen thanks for your response i´m sorry, i updated my question with this definition ['register']

Comment: @scorpions78 please show your code with the button.

Comment: @Tolbxela i updated my question with your requirements

Comment: @scorpions78 is not enough. Where is the function `searchRegisters()` defined?

Comment: @Tolbxela i´m sorry, i shared all my script in my parent component. In this component i´m including my other component and i have my action button

Comment: @Tolbxela i want use composition API only... maybe i don´t apply well examples. I´m sorry

Comment: @scorpions78 I knew it. You should better don't mix Options API with Composition API.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2**

In the `setup()` function, you have to use `Composition API`

With `Composition API` you get the `emit` function in the `setup()` over the [Setup Context](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#setup-context).

Check my first sample:

You get the `emit` function over

```
setup(props, { emit })
```

and use it then directly

```
emit("registers", getCall(toRef(param_search,'param_search')))
```

In your case you pass the Setup Context, so you can call `emit` over `context`

```
context.emit("registers", getCall(toRef(param_search,'param_search')))
```

It looks like you don't really need to define your custom event, but I would still recommend it:

```
emits: ['registers']
```

Note that, the `this.$emit()` call is used by `Options API`, and not `Composition API`

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const MyComp = {
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const emitMyEvent = (event) => emit('registers', event);
    return { emitMyEvent }
  },
  template: `<button id="my-button" @click="emitMyEvent">emit</button>`
}

const App = { 
  components: { MyComp },
  setup() {
    const getCall = (event) => console.log('getCall(): ' + event.target.id);
    return { getCall }
  }
  
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <my-comp @registers="getCall"></my-comp> 
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

The same with `Options API` using `this.$emit`

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const MyComp = {
  emits: ['registers'],  
  methods: {
    emitMyEvent: function(event) { this.$emit('registers', event) }
  },
  template: `<button id="my-button" @click="emitMyEvent">emit</button>`
}

const App = { 
  components: { MyComp },
  methods: {
    getCall: (event) => console.log('getCall(): ' + event.target.id)
  } 
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <my-comp @registers="getCall"></my-comp> 
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank your very much for your help and your time, but i can´t apply your code... I understand but my button, not run. i don´t know if i have to do this line template: `<button id="my-button" @click="emitMyEvent">emit</button>` and maybe your solution it´s for Options API i´m using composition API, i´m sorry that i believe i didn´t say it

Comment: @scorpions78 I have added the Options API version

Comment: thank you very much. I´m using composition API, i think that it´s first?

Comment: Yes, it's first one

Comment: You can call `emit` over `context.emit("registers", getCall(toRef(param_search,'param_search')))`

Comment: thanks for your response. console return Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit' when i try send my form. updated my question. With all my parent component code.

Comment: Do it so `setup(props, { emit })` or so `setup(props, context)`, not both at the same time! And please read the docs before you try!

Comment: i´m sorry for my mistake. I fixed it, but i have a problem. When i clicked my button, and i setted data in my form i can show data in my console in tab network, but i can´t fill my table. this @registers="getCall" not filled my table. I don´t know that i´m doing wrong... Update my question with my v-for